# micronaut multiple datasource encypted password

Tags: jdbc, jdbctemplate, micronaut

I created a micronaut application that has access to multiple datasources through jdbctemplate.  I configured the jdbctemplates like so:

```
@Factory
@Requires(beans = DatasourceFactory.class)
public class JdbcTemplateFactory {

    @Context
    @EachBean(DataSource.class)
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

This uses `io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.tomcat.DatasourceFactory` which consumes my configuration yml:

```
datasources:
  datasource111111:
    url: url
    username: username
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  datasource222222:
    url: url
    username: username
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

The issue is I want to somehow decrypt the password coming from configuration.  My first attempt is to "replace" the `DatasourceConfiguration` bean that the factory is using but no luck, it gives me an error (io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException) that doesn't make sense.

Here's my replace attempt:

```
@Replaces(DatasourceConfiguration.class)
@EachProperty(value = BasicJdbcConfiguration.PREFIX, primary = "default")
public class EncryptedDatasourceConfiguration extends DatasourceConfiguration {
    public EncryptedDatasourceConfiguration(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return "encrypted password";
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong??  Thanks!

Answer:
Had to listen to bean creation as suggested

```
@Singleton
public class DatasourceInitiliazer implements BeanCreatedEventListener<DatasourceConfiguration> {
    @Override
    public DatasourceConfiguration onCreated(BeanCreatedEvent<DatasourceConfiguration> event) {
        final DatasourceConfiguration datasource = event.getBean();
        datasource.setPassword("encryptedPassword");
        return datasource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely better off creating a `BeanCreatedEventListener` that reads the password, decrypts it, and sets it back on the configuration

Comment: Cool!  that works.  Not that I need it because I'm only decrypting the password but is there a way to get the qualifier of the bean?  Just wondering

Comment: Yep see https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-flyway/blob/3513638cbf5c496fe49340ade95bcd6216c925ee/flyway/src/main/java/io/micronaut/configuration/dbmigration/flyway/DataSourceMigrationRunner.java#L52